# File upload through form type file

Tags: forms, files

**My Drupal version is 8.6.10**

I am trying to upload a file through the [file_save_upload](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_save_upload/8.6.x) function and the function is looking for the file in

**Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag Object**

```
$all_files = \Drupal::request()->files;
debug($all_files);

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag Object
(
    [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

But my file is in

**Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object.**

```
$all_files = \Drupal::request()->request;
debug($all_files);

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object
(
    [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 4
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [image_section] => logo_capnord.png
                )

            [op] => Ajouter
            [form_build_id] => form-wMTrCGaN5mPlOOv8bqS7UsJ0lRiSN6QQp9UviA0cTIA
            [form_token] => 1hTMXJRfoQvFV9Lqq3TuJ29eYC6L-zt3U7Bow1P8yJ0
            [form_id] => capnord_section_form_list
        )

)
```

The field is generated through the reloading of the form in ajax.

```
  $form["base"]["fields"] += [
    "image_section" => [
      "#type" => "file",
      "#title" => "Image",
    ]
  ];
```

Comment: I solved my problem, as I only reloaded one part of the form, the form generator did not know that there was a file element, so it did not add "multipart enctype / form-data" to the form.

Comment: If you found a solution please enter it in as an answer

Comment: I didn't know that i can answer to myself, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
$form["#attributes"] = ["enctype" => "multipart/form-data"];

$form["base"]["fields"] += [
   "image_section" => [
    "#type" => "file",
    "#title" => "Image",
   ]
];
```

I solved my problem, as I only reloaded one part of the form, the form generator did not know that there was a file element, so it did not add "multipart enctype / form-data" to the form.

I hope this will help someone in the same situation as me in the future.